# How to insert value using ajax into database?

Tags: php, javascript

Here I am getting the counter value using javascript.
I want to insert those counter value into my database.
How can I do it? Please suggest me.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var counter = 1;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;
</script>
```

Comment: use ajax and post it to php, then save it to db.

Comment: At what point do you want the counter value inserted, and what kind of database? You'll have to elaborate on exactly what you want if you don't want this question to be closed.

Comment: im just to know how to use
'xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=",true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.location.reload();

}'

Answer (score 0):

please read [W3school ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) and click on try it yourself button I am sure that you will easily get that :)